# jQuery 1.5 click functions bug?

Tags: jquery-1.5

Have same js code:

```
$("#pr_list .c").bind({
   click: function(event) {
       var m = $(this);
       var u = m.attr("rel");

       var lOpen = $("div.txt[rel="+u+"]");
       lOpen.html("!!!").slideDown();
   }
});
```

Have same html code

```
<div id="pr_list">
    <div class="w c" rel="1">same text</div>
    <div class="txt" rel="1" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="w c" rel="2">same text2</div>
    <div class="txt" rel="2" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

When click on "same text" opens all div with class txt, not check same rel attr.. why?

Update:
Ок, how about real example: http://jsfiddle.net/3nYXA

Comment: Can you show a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo with this happening?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8FAq/ Works for me, once I've corrected the class name error (`txt` vs `text`).

Comment: I edited the `txt` to `text` without mentioning. Assumed it was a typo since it shouldn't behave like described. Rolled back in order to avoid (too much) confusion :)

Comment: sorry, in div class txt, my typo, but code does not work..

Comment: same example in post :) (real code from site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has problem in here.

```
var lOpen = $("div.txt[rel="+u+"]");
```

You should change this to:

```
var lOpen = $("div.txt[rel='"+u+"']");
```

Quotation marks were missed. It was fine at jQuery 1.4.x, but from jQuery 1.5 it doesn't work.

Check this out. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 2):

Works just fine: http://www.jsfiddle.net/JxEsK/

You got a typo in the selector for the `.text`.

Comment: @Alvain: the slash `/` must be escaped in a jQuery selector. See my update: http://jsfiddle.net/3nYXA/1/

Answer (score 1):

In your sample, the class names txt and text are mixed, this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/N9EDj/

Comment: note the extra quotes around the rel attribute it's totally make my answer better than jAndy one ^^

Comment: the extra quotes don't make any difference in this case.

Comment: it was a joke but in the jQuery doc: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ it says "Attribute values in selector expressions must be surrounded by quotation marks.". Anyway accept jAndy answer, he replied before me